# Migrating table contents to the other table and changing the rules of the game Mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm stuck yet again with mysql :)

My issue is simple/complicated at the same time.

I prepared dataset which contains columns:
`user_id, user_email, user_country` .......

I need to import/insert this into wp_usermeta table.

wp_usermeta has following columns:

```
umeta_id (autoincrement), user_id, meta_key, meta_value
```

So from my dataset, user_id should be user_id, user_email and user_country become meta_keys and their content meta_values.

In the end I expect to get this:

```
user_id   meta_key        meta_value
12        user_country    Italy
12        user_email      sa@sa.com
```

From the lack of correct word for this, I'm trying to "deconstruct" dataset.

Possible with mysql? or should I do php script that will do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking to do this with a php loop.

Create a query within your script that grabs all of the rows you're looking to bring over.

And then do a `while` loop that traverses over the results and within that you can do a foreach loop that pulls out the key and value.

Look at the PHP manuel for `mysqli_fetch_array`. Also, look at [this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#104189) in particular.